# Cannot convert value of type '[any Product]' to expected argument type '[Product]'

Tags: swift

I am dealing with this func

```
public func fetchProduct(productIdentifiers: Set<String>, handler: ((_ result: Result<[Product], InAppPurchase.Error>) -> Void)? = nil) {
    productProvider.fetch(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers, requestId: UUID().uuidString) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let products):
            handler?(.success(products.map({ Internal.Product($0) })))
        case .failure(let error):
            handler?(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}
```

the context is this

```
  let iap = InAppPurchase.default
  iap.fetchProduct(productIdentifiers: [productID], handler: { (result) in
    switch result {
    case .success(let products):
      // Use products
      runOnProductPurchased?(products) //1
```

the last line closure is defined like this

```
typealias handlerPurchased = ([Product])->Void
var runOnProductPurchased: handlerPurchased?
```

Product is

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

struct Product {
  private let skProduct: SKProduct
  
  init(_ skProduct: SKProduct) {
    self.skProduct = skProduct
  }
}
```

But this line in //1 shows this error

> Cannot convert value of type '[any Product]' to expected argument type '[Product]'

why? Isn't `products` an array of `Product`?

Comment: `Product` is also a name used in `StoreKit`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product

Comment: you are right @jnpdx. Please convert your comment to an answer. So I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Product` is also a name used in `StoreKit`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product

Your namespace conflict is leading to the compiler error. I suggest renaming your `Product` to something unused in `StoreKit`